# how do i mock method, calling one method from another method?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

I'm New in Mocking. 
I've a service I'm trying to call is let say name A, I need to test someMethod.

```
@Service
public class A {



private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private final CoreXReader coreXReader;

    @Autowired
    B b;

    @Autowired
    C c;


    @Async
    public void someMethod(Config config) throws Exception {
        pushConfig(config);
    }

    private void pushConfig(Config config) throws Exception {

        String url = config.getBaseurl() + config.getId(); 
        ABCRestClient restClient = new ABCRestClient(url);

            String jobJson = restClient.callRestMethod(HttpMethod.GET, "");

    } 

}
```

sample of ABCRestClient

```
  public class ABCRestClient {
        private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());


        private String url;

        public ABCRestClient(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }


        public String callRestMethod(HttpMethod method, String payload) throws Exception {
            someresponse="example response";
            return someresponse;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to test by creating mockSpy but it still Calling its 'callRestMethod'

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest // (webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private A a;



    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Before
    public void prepareMockDataForService() throws Exception {

        ABCRestClient apiClient = new ABCRestClient(config.getBaseurl() + config.getId() );
        ABCRestClient apiClientSpy=Mockito.spy(apiClient);

        doReturn(getCallResponse()).when(apiClientSpy).callRestMethod(HttpMethod.GET, "");


    }

    @Test
    public void TestPushConfig() throws Exception {
        a.someMethod(StubDataGenerator.getConfig());

    }

    private String getCallResponse() {
        return "{"msg":"sample response"}";
    }

}
```

i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here why its calling the actual *callRestMethod* as i already create a spy .

I tried using this too `Mockito.doReturn(getCallResponse()).when(apiClientSpy.callRestMethod(HttpMethod.GET, ""))`

Also, is there any difference in these two statement if I use it `Mockito.doReturn()` or directly `doReturn()`? In my case both seems behaving same.

Before I tried with this as well `when().thenReturn();`  but I read somewhere that use `when().thenReturn()` when you actually want to make call. Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: what do you mean: "method inside method"? Does your test class even compile? You are trying to call a private method from outside the class.

Comment: in test i'm hiting this someMethod which is calling pushconfig and M trying to mock a method which called inside push config callRestMethod

Comment: yes, but in your test you can't call pushconfig, because that is a private method in your A class. You would need a mock for the restclient there, but since that is a local variable, not a field, it can't be mocked.

Comment: these classes are sample class my code is compiling. and calling callRestMethod

Comment: the code you posted won't compile, for the obvious reason I mentioned earlier. You can't mock that method call, for the other reason I mentioned.

Comment: I've update my question I'm calling someMethod in my test. 

what would u suggest? what would be the right way how can i test it i need to avoid actual ABCRestClient  calls

Answer (score 0):

You can try mock instead of spy:

```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @SpringBootTest // (webEnvironment= 
   SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
   public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private A a;



    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Before
    public void prepareMockDataForService() throws Exception {

        ABCRestClient apiClientSpy=Mockito.mock(ABCRestClient.class);

        doReturn(getCallResponse()).when(apiClientSpy).callRestMethod(HttpMethod.GET, "");


    }

    @Test
    public void TestPushConfig() throws Exception {
        a.someMethod(StubDataGenerator.getConfig());

    }

    private String getCallResponse() {
        return "{"msg":"sample response"}";
    }
  }
```

Comment: what about the constructor Argument? and it still calling the actual callRestMethod